# Separate one column to some column in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have table with one column called **cols**. I want to separate **cols** to new column based on type: SKU and MARK using bigquery.

```
cols

"dsc":[{"amount":30000,"c_amount":0,"d_amount":0,"d_id":"","scope":"CART","title":"Promo","type":"SKU"},{"amount":7000,"c_amount":0,"d_amount":7000,"d_id":"x","scope":"CART_D","title":"","type":"MARK"}]
```

The result i want is like:

```
sku_amount sku_c_amount sku_d_amount sku_d_id sku_scope sku_title mark_amount  mark_c_amount  mark_d_amount mark_d_id mark_scope
30000       0            0                     CART     Promo      7000         0             0               x           CART_D
```

Anyone know the script? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
create temp table temp_table as 
  select id1,  
    max(if(key = 'type', value, null)) over (partition by id1, id2) || '_' || key as key,
    value, offset
  from (
    select md5(cols) as id1, md5(json) id2, arr[offset(0)] as key, arr[offset(1)] as value, offset
    from your_table, unnest(json_extract_array('{' || cols || '}', '$.dsc')) json with offset, 
    unnest(split(translate(json, '{}"', ''))) kv, 
    unnest([struct(split(kv, ':') as arr)])
  );

execute immediate (select '''
select * except(id1) from (select * except(offset) from temp_table)
pivot (any_value(value) for key in ("''' || string_agg(key, '","' order by offset, key) || '''"))
'''
from (select distinct key, offset from temp_table where not ends_with(key, '_type'))
);
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: have you tried? does it work for you?

Comment: hii thank youu. i will try yaa